# Issues while switching from jQuery Validate 1.7 to 1.11

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

We just moved our application from jQuery Validate 1.7 to 1.11 and modified the code in all the Views to be in sync with the 1.10 version.

However, for a scenario, `validate.js` is throwing null object exception.

I have narrowed down to a function in js from which this exception is thrown but unable to reach the specific LOC that is causing the issue / is incompatible with the new version.

While troubleshooting, I used the 1.7 version of `validate.js` and everything seems to work fine.

Could anyone share any information on how can I debug(tool/any other way) or resolve this issue?

Note: I can not share the code.

**Resolution:**
Please let me know, if this is the right way to solve this issue or i need to change my algorithm.

This issue was coming up while moving from Case 2 to Case 1(see comment in question) as in this scenario , only the checked 'check-boxes' are posted back to the server instead of the group.

So, validationtargetFor fails in validate.js as the passed in element is a control and not a group so `index [0]` throws error

```
validationTargetFor: function (element) {
            // if radio/checkbox, validate first element in group instead

        if ( this.checkable(element) ) {
         element = this.findByName( element.name ).not(this.settings.ignore)[0];
        }
        return element;
        },
```

Changed it to:

```
validationTargetFor: function (element) {
            // if radio/checkbox, validate first element in group instead

            if (this.checkable(element)) {
                if (this.findByName(element.name).not(this.settings.ignore)[0] == undefined)
                    return element;
                else
                    return this.findByName(element.name).not(this.settings.ignore)[0];
            }

            return element;
        },
```

Comment: use debugger tools like firebug (FF), developer tools (Chrome). can you share url?

Comment: *"While troubleshooting, I used the 1.7 version of validate.js and everything seems to work fine."* so including the latest version of the validate plugin makes it work properly? why can't you just do that and move on?

Comment: because 1.7 version is the older version from which we have upgraded to 1.11. So, as a desperate measure ran the code with older version of validate.js and it worked fine. Hope it clears the confusion.

Comment: If you cannot share the code, then this is off-topic for SO.  As per the FAQ, questions about problems with code must show enough code in the question to replicate the issue.

Comment: I can share the details of the scenario, our app is used for answering surveys and as per certain business rules questions we hide/show questions. 
This issue comes up when a dependent question with check-box responses(multiple ans) changes visibility state. e.g

Case 1:
Q. Are you happy?
A. Y 
-----------
Case 2:
Q. Are you happy?
A: N
  - What happened? (Multiple select check-box group)

Issue is coming up when the scenario changes intially from Case 2 to Case 1.(Changing the response for "Are you happy?")

Comment: We don't need to see anything proprietary... you simply need to **construct a generic demo** that replicates the issue.

Comment: **Quote OP:** _" Please let me know, if this is the right way to solve this issue or i need to change my algorithm."_ ~ if you edited the plugin itself, then this is definitely not the right way to solve the issue. (you might as well not upgrade it at all, just use the version that works.)  You'd be better off figuring out what part of _your_ code is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Sparky..
I changed the code in the views and that fixed the issue.
Firstly, added all dependent response-controls in a class, say, "skip" and then ignored this class from form validation.

```
("#form").validate({
        groups: { checks: checkbox_names },
        groups: { radios: radiobox_names },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
           //some code            
        },
        ignore: "skip"
    });
```

So, now dynamic questions (dependent questions) are posted back without any issue.